# FRESH INSTALLED MYSQL 5.7 Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'

Tags: mysql, freebsd

I am typing command `mysql_secure_installation`

```
Getting error 2003 can't connect to mysql server on 'xxxxxxxxx' (10060 unknown error )
```

On Navicat Mysql when trying to connect

and this error shows up

```
root@vps:~ # mysql_secure_installation
mysql_secure_installation: [ERROR] unknown variable 'prompt=\u@\h [\d]>\_'

Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Connecting to MySQL server using password in '/root/.mysql_secret'
Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (38)
root@vps:~ #
```

in vps.server.com.err

```
2020-05-24T21:56:09.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/db/mysql/vps.server.com.err'.
2020-05-24T21:56:09.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/db/mysql
2020-05-24T21:56:09.688684Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2020-05-24T21:56:09.697718Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER' sql mode was not set.
2020-05-24T21:56:09.736394Z 0 [Note] /usr/local/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.30-log) starting as process 1923 ...
2020-05-24T21:56:09.853398Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-05-24T21:56:09.853444Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-05-24T21:56:09.853452Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2020-05-24T21:56:09.853458Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-05-24T21:56:09.861651Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-05-24T21:56:09.873603Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2020-05-24T21:56:09.878255Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 1G, instances = 8, chunk size = 128M
2020-05-24T21:56:10.014801Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-05-24T21:56:10.043702Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The Auto-extending innodb_system data file '/var/db/mysql/ibdata1' is of a different size 1152 pages (rounded down to MB) than specified in the .cnf file: initial 8192 pages, max 0 (relevant if non-zero) pages!
2020-05-24T21:56:10.043735Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2020-05-24T21:56:10.252471Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2020-05-24T21:56:10.252517Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2020-05-24T21:56:10.252526Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
2020-05-24T21:56:10.252532Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2020-05-24T21:56:10.253467Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2020-05-24T21:56:10.262501Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2020-05-24T21:56:10.263005Z 0 [Note] /usr/local/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2020-05-24T21:56:10.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/db/mysql/vps.server.com.pid ended
```

Comment: you have to add some infomration to the command see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-secure-installation.html

Comment: error 2003 can't connect to mysql server on 'localhost' (10060 unknown error ) on Navicat mysql

Comment: This error is often caused by starting MySQL, then changing the `my.cnf` file, and starting MySQL again. You may need to delete the `ibdata1` file created during the initial installation so that it can be regenerated at the correct size.